# Lighthouse returned error: FAILED_DOCUMENT_REQUEST

Tags: pagespeed-insights

For website: https://www.hogroastsdevon.com/

I'm getting the following error:

> Lighthouse returned error: FAILED_DOCUMENT_REQUEST. Lighthouse was
>   unable to reliably load the page you requested. Make sure you are
>   testing the correct URL and that the server is properly responding to
>   all requests. (Details: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT)

The site and server are working fine, but the site has seen a drop in rankings since getting the error earlier this week.

Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: I have this error when trying to test an internal site that's only accessible on our company network.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who gets this one possible cause is if you have something like `Mod Sec` running on the server. If you test the site too often it will block the IP address temporarily.

I discovered this when a new client showed me their search console data and after a certain point all pages returned `site unavailable` crawl errors and this tied in with me receiving the same error the OP had.

It is unusual for this to happen on a properly configured server (theirs was a mess) but is one place to look.

It also explains a drop in rankings if you have forgotten to use Google Search Console.

Comment: This isn't the case for me because I am trying to test a site which is accessible by white-list only IP's but I am not sure what IP to white-list for Lighthouse to reach it. The site is only available on our company network, It's a QA site.

Comment: Ask a new question for this @ApexFred and I will help you there.